# Timing chain tensioner broke apart, piece dropped into engine

Tags: timing-chain, tensioner

'07 cobalt LS 2.2 L ecotec; 70K miles

Car had chain noise on startup, so I decided to replace the (timing chain) tensioner. This was straightforward, until I took the old one out. It had come apart, and when the body and spring were removed, the piston appears to have fallen. From what I've seen of this engine's anatomy, it looks like the fallen piece(s?) might have just dropped into the timing chain 'chest'; or (worse), they could have gotten into the base.

My plan is to pull the TC cover, and see what I find. If anyone has ideas/experience with this, I'd appreciate hearing.

Comment: Most likely it will be in the bottom of the timing chain cover, but if not, when you remove the cover you can then see where else it might have gone. There will probably be an oil drain hole into the sump for the chain lubrication, but it's unlikely to be big enough for anything to disappear into it. Even if it has ended up in the sump, getting it out is a simple enough job.

Comment: A magnet on the end of a stick is a wonderful thing... always in my box...